# How to hardcode the entity varchar value?

Tags: guidewire, gosu

The requirement is to store the hardcoded value for varchar which is in an entity file(.eti). I tried adding to the **default** option but it is not reflecting.

Answer (score 3):

Default option works well with boolean values (true/false), typelists (you can choose a default typecode), monetary amounts too, but it looks like it is not allowed to specify a default varchar. 
Therefore the easiest way would be to create a preupdate rule which inserts that default value every time when you create a new record in the database.

Preupdate rule example:

```
  @gw.rules.RuleName("YourEntityAssignDefaultValue")
internal class YourEntityAssignDefaultValueRule {
  static function doCondition(yourEntity : entity.YourEntity) : boolean {
    return yourEntity.New
  }

  static function doAction(yourEntity : entity.YourEntity, actions : gw.rules.Action) {
    yourEntity.yourColumn = "defaultValue"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve through getter and setter properties in an appropriate enhancement class.

```
  public property get PolicyNumber(): String {
      return  this.PolicyNumber  }
```

and somewhere class you must be assigned the value to the **PolicyNumber**  field then it will reflect.

Comment: @Harshu ganesh Just remember that this solution not grants you value in database, make sure that you don't need it. (for example for db reports purpose)